# PWM delay without blocking the code

Tags: programming, pwm

I want my LED to turn on gradually without using the `delay()` function and blocking the code.

Here's the code i came up with:

```
int led_pin = 6;
unsigned long millisTimer = 0;
int PWMdelay = 5000;
int condition = 0;
int i = 0;
void setup() {
    pinMode(led_pin, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
    if(condition == 1){
    if ((millis() - millisTimer) > PWMdelay){
        if(i<255){
            i++;
            millisTimer = millis();
        }

    }
        analogWrite(led_pin, i);
    }
}
```

Is this the "right way" of slowing the PMW duration from 0 to 255 or there are alternative/better/easier ways?

Comment: Seems ok for fade in timer. Why are you doing the else with `i--`? Do you want to fade out the LED after the fade in? That does not work this way, since it will only vary between 254 and 255.

Comment: the Fade example in IDE uses delay, but shows how to go up and then down. and put `millisTimer = millis();` outside if-else

Comment: @chrisl newbie mistakes... thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: From my personal definition, the "right way" is a way that works. So, does it work? Your approach is a common way to do tasks without delay (like in the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example)

Comment: @SimSon i'm new to this and i don't know how others write code in "standard way", thought asking may open new doors to learn new things.

Comment: see the Fade example and the BlinkWithoutDelay example in IDE Examples menu

Comment: @Juraj okay thanks.

Comment: That's fine, I do it the same way

Comment: all code inside `if(condition == 1){` block, except the `analogWrite()`, should be indented one more level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my take at this - I've followed the example code mentioned by other members and here is "FadeWithoutDelay"

```
const int ledPin = 11;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;        // will store last time LED was updated
const long interval = 100;               // fade interval (milliseconds)
int brightness = 0;                      // how bright the LED is
int fadeAmount = 5;                      // how many points to fade the LED by

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  // set the digital pin as output:
}
void loop() 
{
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) 
  {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;         // save the last state
    analogWrite(ledPin, brightness);        // Set the brightness
    brightness = brightness + fadeAmount;   // change the brightness for next time through the loop
    // reverse the direction of the fading at the ends of the fade:
    if (brightness <= 0 || brightness >= 255) 
    {
      fadeAmount = -fadeAmount;
    }
  }
}
```